# Attaching outdoor Ethernet cable to stucco?

Tags: ethernet, stucco

I need to route the Gigabit Ethernet CAT6 cable on the outside wall. The cable is certified for outdoor use, but I'm puzzled how to attach it to stucco. Would I need to drill stucco with masonry bit and use something like that: [https://www.amazon.com/Aluminum-Cable-Clips-Stucco-Surfaces/dp/B009XGON8W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009XGON8W) or there is a way to do it without drilling? Can it be glued to stucco?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stucco clips linked in the question should be OK, as long as they are big enough that they don't damage the cable.

Flex Clips are popular with the cable companies

[image: flex clip]

you drill and use a plastic anchor with these

[image: plastic anchor]

It is going to sag a bit between anchors, but the closer you space them, the less it will sag.

Gluing it would be a mess - I would not recommend that.

Comment: Would use screw in over those drive in style, 1 missed hit or drive two far and the cable is toast.+

Comment: @edbeal thats a good point - you can mangle the cable - plus you can also ding the stucco with the hammer.